# How should I set the build.gradle when building the app?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I am trying to build the app using the following command.

```
/android
gradlew assembleRelease
```

However, I am wondering if I need to remove the debug of signingConfigs and debug of buildTypes when in release mode or not?

this is my code

(android/app/build.gradle)

```
              signingConfigs {

                    release {
                        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
                        }
                    }

                    debug {
                        storeFile file('debug.keystore')
                        storePassword 'android'
                        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
                        keyPassword 'android'
                    }
                }
                buildTypes {
                    debug {
                        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                    }
                    release {
                        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
                        // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
                        
                            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
                    
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need. When building for release mode, gradle will automatically select the configs mentioned in the release section. What you specify as the configuration for release mode is important.

Comment: thank you but buildTypes in release should i change signingConfig signingConfigs.debug to signingConfig signingConfigs.release.  is right?? or should i leave both ( signingConfig signingConfigs.debug, signingConfig signingConfigs.release )????

Comment: In release, you should point it to release keys that you have generated.

Comment: what you mean is that if i want to build in release mode  in  buildTypes in release i should signingConfig signingConfigs.debug to signingConfig signingConfigs.release. ??? is right?

Comment: @user15322469 - Yes, that is correct. If you don’t change it, the release build will contain debug key information, which is a security threat. You should create your own release keys and change signingConfigs.debug to signingConfigs.release.